# I have a array of objects containing images and documents, I want to check the mime_type and pick the first element (React) to display in <img> tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a array of objects which contain images and documents, I want to check is the mime_type is 'images/jpeg' or 'image/png' and then only display the first image in a  tag. I am using react.

I tried this but I keep getting undefined

```
<img className={"img-fluid img-list"} 
   src={this.state.images.filter(img => (img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png') || {})[0].blob_url} 
   alt="" />


<img className={"img-fluid img-list"} 
   src={this.state.images.filter(img => (img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png'))[0].blob_url} 
   alt="" />
```

if check with a {} i dont get any links

any help much appriciated.

Comment: If you want only the first image, you can use `Array.prototype.find()`; you should end up with something like this:  `src={((this.state.images.find(item => (item.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || item.mime_type === 'image/png')) || {}).blob_url) || ''`

Comment: @secan Thank you, I/ve been scratching my head but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here:

```js
this.state.images.filter(img => (img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png') || {})[0].blob_url
```

It should be:

```js
((this.state.images.filter(img => (img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png')) || [])[0] || {}).blob_url
```

If you add a bit of indentation, it should be more clear where your error was:

```js
(
  (
    this.state.images.filter(img => (
      img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png'
    ))     // give me an array with only the images
    || []  // OR give me back an empty array if you cannot find any
  )[0]     // then give me the first element (image object) of the array
  || {}    // OR give me back an empty object if the array is empty
).blob_url // finally give me the `blobl_url` of the object
```

Alternatively, you can use `Array.prototype.find`, which will return the first item matching the criteria:

```js
(this.state.images.find(img => (img.mime_type === 'image/jpeg' || img.mime_type === 'image/png')) || {}).blob_url
```